# Rails vendor/cache include gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, vendor

A few days ago I installed a rails project from my work, after finishing the installation I was surprised that when i run 'bundle install' it creates the folder: "vendor/cache" that contains countless files related to the gems that use the project 
.

I leave you a [link](https://i.ibb.co/KqXV83R/Screen-Shot-2022-05-23-at-08-56-25.png) of what the folder contains  . 
Any idea how to fix it?
Thanks for reading me

Comment: Check your <project>/.bundle/config or `~/.bundle/config`, there is probably a setting to cache gems.

Comment: This link is the content of the file: 
[link](https://i.ibb.co/Gdh8PCc/Screen-Shot-2022-05-23-at-09-39-03.png) 
is the correct file ?